How to store row-position in a database?
I am looking to emulate a feature in Excel/Google Sheets where there is a table of data, but someone may move a row up or down. Here is an example of the interaction:

My first thought as to how to store this in a database table would be by storing an unsigned INT4 with the row position. For example, if the table has two fields, name and age then the table would have the following structure:
`row_num`   `name`    `age`
 1           tom      10
 2           angel    20

And then if, for example, the 2nd row was moved before the first row, the row_num would be changed for both of those. However, I'm wondering what might be a more efficient way to do this. Suppose I have a billion rows and I move the second-to-last-row to the second-to-first: all 1B of the row_nums would need to be updated. I suppose doing an UPDATE statement such as the following might be one way to do this:
UPDATE myTbl row_num=CASE 
                        WHEN $moved_selection...
                        WHEN $changed_section...
                      ELSE row_num END

But I'm wondering if there might be a better way to do this?

Why?  Are you planning to serve up all 1 Billion rows to a user?  My first thought is that ordering like what you've explained should be handled in the UI / report  / whatever is being given to the user, and not in the database.  If you do want to do this in the database, what triggers a row re-ordering?  That could be key in determining how this would be implemented in the db. Can only one row be re-ordered at a time?  What if you get two requests to re-order x number of rows?

@devlincarnate well let's say then instead of a Billion it's a million, which would be what Excel would store. So there may be up to a million limit. If the sorting is handled in the sort though, there cannot be an arbitrary sort aside from the columns then, right? Meaning, a user could not 'move' a row like they would do in a spreadsheet.

For example, instead of an UPDATE statement, why not use a SELECT statement that has the definitions for how the data should be ordered?

As a purely intellectual exercise - you could just store the preceding id (first row's preceding_id will be null) then a recursive query to unravel it. That way in your second example only the 3rd row, last row, and row getting moved would get updated. Of course then you bite the bullet of having a recursive query run every time you want the results displayed in this ordering.

@Error_2646 yea I think that might make the select take more time than the update. The good thing about the update approach is it's one time and then done, whereas this approach uses the recursive query every time the data is viewed.

@devlincarnate I don't follow, wouldn't you need to store the row-numbers in the table anyways? Say you have 5 rows, and the user moves one row before another (in an arbitrary way), how would you 'save' that sort, you would either need to store a number in the table or have it externally 'in the ui' and build the sort after the query is returned.

Sorry, I think I'm unclear about the process you're trying to implement, and that confusion started with the concept that you're serving up 1 Billion or even 1 Million rows to a user on a repeated basis. and that the user then has some type of arbitrary row ordering in mind on a data set that's so huge they can't possibly consume it all in a way that makes arbitrary ordering important. I'm struggling to wrap my brain around the use-case, so I'll just dip out of the conversation.

@David542 If I had to do this I might consider a materialized view to mitigate that. So the materialized view only gets updated when there is a change to the underlying data. But that's if I had a gun to my head and had to do it.

The premise is false. A relational database is not positional (text file, Excel) or navigational (back to the 60s?). in rbds the position of rows does not have any meaning. If you want to store some synthetic position you are probably better off with some non-relational solution. But +1 for the fringe question, as always.

Make the row priority be a floating point number. Keep an index on the row priority.
Updating a row's position is just a question of updating the row to a value between the existing two. Getting a page starting at a given row is grabbing a fixed number of records in order of priority, starting at a known priority. This is very fast off of the index.
Occasionally the wrong series of inserts can leave no floating point between those numbers. In that case you can easily grab a window of rows, and fix priorities to evenly space between them. The logic for this fix is complicated, but the need for them is very rare.
What will be hard is grabbing the window from rows 1500000 to 1500049. If that is a specific use case that you actually encounter, you can hack it by maintaining an auxiliary table that is randomly one row out of 32,000, along with a count of how many are between it and the next. Now you can query the auxiliary table to get a row of known position near to your desired one, then do a second query to find the row at the position that you want to start at. Then get your window.
Of course if you get that far, you'd be better off just using a data structure which is specialized to handle this use case. Not many databases have this built in. Offhand, the only one which comes to my mind is the Redis sorted set, and that's not SQL. However the code for that shows you how to roll your own if you wish to go outside of a SQL database for this.
